# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on boot with Nvidia driver installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

I'm trying to get a second display to work via the HDMI port on a GeForce 1030. It works if I boot into Windows, but not in Ubuntu.

`ubuntu-drivers devices` returns:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001D01sv00001028sd000011C7bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP108 [GeForce GT 1030]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

So I ran `sudo apt get nvidia-driver-396` which succeeded. I setup the MOK password when prompted. I rebooted, then went through the "enroll MOK" flow. Ubuntu then shows the boot log for a time then hangs, the last command being "Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service" which I assume is irrelevant. I'm able to start a session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and uninstall the drivers with `sudo apt purge nvidia*`, then successfully `sudo reboot`.

I am also unable to boot with the `nvidia-driver-390` version.

Any help debugging?

Update:

I checked out the systemctl log while it's hanging and it's full of repeated log items from "nvidia-persistenced" that look like:

```
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: Verbose syslog connection opened
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: Now running with user ID 123 and group ID 129
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: Started (1399)
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: Local RPC service initialized
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: Received signal 15
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: Socket closed.
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: PID file unlocked.
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: PID file closed.
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Aug 23 17:23:48 brianubuntu nvidia-persistenced[1399]: Shutdown (1399)
```

edit:
I attempted all the potential fixes in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) including purging and the reinstalling drivers from TTY, trying older versions of the drivers, and booting with different GRUB settings. Still no luck.

Comment: File a bug report with nvidia and use the open source driver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) and [How do I install the nVidia Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)